# node js gettting error of activity timeout or database connection lost

Tags: node.js

I am using node js script to sync data(for multiple users) from GeoTab    server APIs to my local db and using below code

```
     var syncUsers = function () {
     for (var i = 0; i < geotabUsers.length; i++) {


         if (apiInstanse[geotabUsers[i].userId] == undefined)
         {
              apiInstanse[geotabUsers[i].userId] = new API(geotabUsers[i].apiUsername, geotabUsers[i].apiPassword, geotabUsers[i].apiDatabase, js_lang.GEOTAB_SERVER);
          }

          syncStatusData(apiInstanse[geotabUsers[i].userId], i, userInfo[geotabUsers[i].userId].statusDataFromVersion, geotabUsers[i].userId, userInfo[geotabUsers[i].userId].currentCompany, geotabUsers[i].apiUsername, geotabUsers[i].apiPassword, geotabUsers[i].apiDatabase);

}



var syncStatusData = function (api, i, fromVersion, userId, currentCompany, apiUsername, apiPassword, apiDatabase){

try {
    api.call(js_lang.GEOTAB_GETFEED_METHOD, {
        typeName: js_lang.GEOTAB_STATUS_DATA,
        resultsLimit: js_lang.GEOTAB_API_LIMIT,
        fromVersion: fromVersion
    }, function (err, data) {

        if (err) {
            console.log('api Call Error:', userId);
            console.log('apiUsername:', apiUsername);
            console.log('apiPassword:', apiPassword);
            console.log('apiDatabase:', apiDatabase);
            console.log('Error', err);
            apiInstanse[userId] = new API(apiUsername, apiPassword, apiDatabase, js_lang.GEOTAB_SERVER);
            return;
        }

        var insertStatus = [];

        var sql = "INSERT INTO " + js_lang.TABLE_STATUS_DATA + " (companyId,dateTime,deviceId ,diagnosticId,value,version,uniqueId,userId,unitOfMeasure ) VALUES ?";


        //iterate data
        if (data.data != undefined)
        {
            for (var key in data.data) {

                if (diagnosticList[data.data[key].diagnostic.id] == undefined)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var thisDate = moment(new Date(data.data[key].dateTime));

                var thisDayDate = thisDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

                //prepare data to insert
                var insertRow = [
                    currentCompany,
                    thisDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss"),
                    data.data[key].device.id,
                    data.data[key].diagnostic.id,
                    data.data[key].data,
                    data.data[key].version,
                    data.data[key].id,
                    userId,
                    diagnosticList[data.data[key].diagnostic.id].unitOfMeasure
                ];
                insertStatus.push(insertRow);

                var todayDate = moment(new Date());
                var todayDayDate = todayDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

                //send alert in case of current day data
                if (todayDayDate == thisDayDate)
                {
                    //send mails in case of high pressure
                    if (diagnosticList[data.data[key].diagnostic.id].unitOfMeasure == js_lang.GEOTAB_PRESSURE_UNIT_STR &&
                            data.data[key].data > js_lang.MAX_PRESSURE &&
                            alertTemplates[userId] != undefined)
                    {
                        console.log('alert time');


                        if (alertTemplates[userId] != undefined)
                        {

                            for (var templateIndex = 0; templateIndex < alertTemplates[userId].length; templateIndex++) {
                                var template = alertTemplates[userId][templateIndex];
                                var res = template.devices.split(",");

                                var index = FUNCTION_CLASS.contains.call(res, data.data[key].device.id)

                                if (index)
                                {
                                    var emailSubject = 'High Pressure Alert';

                                    if (userDevices[userId][data.data[key].device.id].name != undefined)
                                    {
                                        var emailText = 'Vehicle:' + userDevices[userId][data.data[key].device.id].name;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        var emailText = '';
                                    }

                                    var toEmails = template.emails;

                                    var emailHtml = 'Vehicle:' + userDevices[userId][data.data[key].device.id].name + '<br>' + diagnosticList[data.data[key].diagnostic.id].name + ' <br> value:' + data.data[key].data + ' ' + js_lang.GEOTAB_PRESSURE_UNIT_PA + '<br>\
' + js_lang.DATE_TIME + ':' + thisDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss");

                                    //call mail function
                                    sendEmail(toEmails, emailSubject, emailText, emailHtml);

                                }


                            }
                        }



                    }
                }

            }
        }

        if (insertStatus.length > 0)
        {
            connection.query(sql, [insertStatus], function (err) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;                 

                connection.query('UPDATE ' + js_lang.TABLE_USER + ' SET statusDataFromVersion = ? WHERE id = ?',
                        [data.toVersion, userId]);

            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('update user:', userId);

            connection.query('UPDATE ' + js_lang.TABLE_USER + ' SET statusDataFromVersion = ? WHERE id = ?',
                    [data.toVersion, userId]);



        }

        if ((geotabUsers.length - 1) == i)
        {
            console.log('loop ended');
            continueSync();
        }
    });
}
catch (e) {
    continueSync();
}

}

var continueSync = function () {
setTimeout(function () {

    connection.end();

    geotabUsers = [];
    userDevices = [];
    diagnosticList = [];
    userInfo = [];
    alertTemplates = {};

    eventEmitter.emit('getUsers');
}, 60000);
```

}

Its work fine for few iteration but getting random errors like

```
    events.js:85
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: Quit inactivity timeout
```

Or

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
```

Comment: Some services place a limit at which you can call their Apis per seconds. So assuming you had about 500 geotabUsers. you Api would loop 500 times and call the api 500 times depending on the time it returns results that you'd save in your db...They usually do this as a measure to reduce attacks

Comment: yes there is limitation for api call if i use usename and password,to remove this problem i have save api instance to array and use that instance for further api calls ,so this problem is not due to api limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this error while executing app on local, To remove problem I have used pm2 node module for process management.Now its working fine.